# how to read data from csv file and get the token which is generated dynamically in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYvfL.jpg)Facing issue when trying to read the data from the CSV file and simultaneously trying to get the authentication token which is received in the response. Need to pass the same token in the subsequent requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNSFU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV file has only 2 "columns" like:

```
username1,password1
username2,password2
etc.
```

you need to remove the trailing comma from the "Variable names" section.

[image]

Demo:

[image]

You can see what JMeter Variables are defined along with their respective values using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination.

More information: [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)

Comment: Thanks, i'm able to read the CSV data, but i need to get the token which is generated on login.

Comment: You can extract it from the response using a suitable JMeter [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save into a variable. Then you will be able to use the variable where required. The process is known as [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) and there is a lot of information on it in the Internet, i.e. [JMeter Regular Expression Extractor: How to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-regular-expressions-extractor)